# Design challenges with high input impedance amplifier

Tags: impedance, input

After a couple of days of reading (also trying to find similar posts) and trial and error in my simulation tool (TINA) I see no other way than consulting you experts.

In my application I have a sensor, then an amplifier, then my filter and at the end of the chain my ADC. Preferably I want to have the whole signal chain fully differential. I am only interested in signals up to 10 kHz. The ADC I would want to use is the [AD7768](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD7768-7768-4.pdf).

The differential input voltage (***U_in***) of my amplifier depends on the ratio of my sensor impedance (***Z_S***) and my amplifier/load impedance (***Z_A***): ***U_in*** ~ ***Z_A***/(***Z_A+Z_S***). Its a simple series connection of both impedances. As ***Z_S*** is very large, I needed to chose an FDA (fully differential amplifier) with a very large differential input impedance:
the [THP210](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/thp210.pdf?ts=1652696753541&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F) with 1 Gohm || 1 pF. Ideally, I want to operate it with unity gain (*G*=1).

However, when I follow the recommendations for the gain resistances ***R_F*** and ***R_I*** (in a range of a couple of kohms) I end up with a much lower ***Z_L*** again and hence a very low input signal/voltage.
[image]

I tested this with trial and error in my simulation tool, as I did not find our or probably did not understand, how to calculate the equivalent input impedance of my amplifier stage (with feedback loop, filter afterwards, ...). So now I have the problem of a low ***Z_A*** and hence low input voltage ***U_in***, even though the amplifiers internal differential impedance is very large.

What I considered now, to keep the overall input impedance of my amplifier stage (***Z_A***) very high, is the following:

**1:** Using open loop gain (***R_F*** --> infinity).
**Problem:** What I read it is not recommended to operate amplifiers with open loop gain for obvious reasons.

**2:** Increase ***R_I*** and ***R_F*** to remain an overall large ***Z_A***.
**Problem:** I need to have ***R_L*** and ***R_F*** in the Gohm range, which is again hard to realize and probably also not wanted from the amplifier operation point of view. Moreover, I get a high-pass behavior of the circuit, which I also do not want. I also wonder how accurate the simulation model of the THP210 is in this range.

**3:** Choosing another amplifier without a feedback loop, to keep a large input resistance. For example the [AD8422](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ad8422.pdf). It has 200 Gohm || 2 pF differential input impedance.
**Problem:** It has no differential output and an insufficient THD performance up to 10 kHz.

[image]

**4:** Using 2 separate amplifiers similar to what is suggested [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/58115/how-to-achieve-high-impedance-input-on-opamp-without-sacrificing-bandwidth). Does this make sense?

At the moment I am lost :(. But I feel it is because of a misunderstanding/missing understanding on my side. So any help is really appreciated, and if it is only to challenge my assumptions. It has been a while since I had one course on electronics at the university.

Comment: You could precede your THP210 circuit with a pair of high impedance opamps as unity gain buffers, almost anything would work to 10 kHz. Perhaps a TL072 (which is very old and needs +/- rails (but you're already using those for the 210))(but there are any number of newer R2R high Z input amps (I rather like LMC6482, low offset, low input current)). The problem is the topology of the THP210, with two 'virtual ground' inputs, that want RI resistors, and hence low input impedance.

Comment: Thank you very much Neil! This really gave me hope now and I will dig deeper into this. My two further questions are in the answer below from Rokta (in case you are interested to follow up). Thanks again, Maxim

Comment: The purpose of the FDA is to centre the two outputs symmetrically around VOCM, which I assumed was necessary in your application. If that's not the case, and you're happy with them being centred around VICM, then only the two unity gain buffers are needed. A small capacitor to ground at the input of each buffer is very good practice, as it will tend to filter out any RF pickup that might disturb the operation of the amplifiers. Look up the topology of the classic '3 amplifier' instrumentation amplifier (without RG), your FDA replaces the third amplifier, but could be replaced by two of those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on right track you just need to go one step further, that is make your own instrumentation amplifier out of [3 opamps](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/semiconductors/chpt-8/the-instrumentation-amplifier/). 2 of them have high input impedance and 1 is fully differential. The input opamps will probably have jfet input to achieve high input impedance (for example max4477). Fully differential opamp selection isnt critical.

Below is simplified schematic (with default values for resistors and capacitors) of fully differential instrumentation amplifier with simple RC filter. I didnt find symbol for FDA so symbol for OA2 isnt correct.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsyK0f.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

PS. Achieving high input impedance (>Gohm) on PCB is hard and require among other things careful planning and cleaning of PCB.

PPS. In comments Aaron mentioned that fully differential instrumentation amplifiers also exist so you are probably better off using them.

Comment: One could also use a instrumentation amp chip, instead of making one...cost vs space. https://www.ti.com/amplifier-circuit/instrumentation/products.html?keyMatch=INSTRUMENTATION%20AMPLIFIER

Comment: Thank you so much! I will dig deeper into that and build a circuit or check for an instrumentation amplifier with differential output. I will mark it as solved once I am there.

Two question: with 2 unity gain high impedance buffer amplifiers (as you recommend), what is the purpose of the third FDA amplifier then (in my case the THP210)? Do I need it still, if I am fine with a gain of 1? 

Second, I would employ a second very simple RC filter at each entrance of the unity gain buffers to limit the signal power at high frequencies and prevent the amplifiers from saturation, any comments?

Comment: @Aaron Interesting, I didnt know that fully differential instrumentation amplifier existed. Oh I see they only have 1 option and even that one is new.

Comment: @Maxim As Aaron suggested you are probably better off with already made chip (if it exist). If you will make you own I suggest you take a closer look at that topology as 2 input opamp arent exactly only buffers. If you want to implement filter and also keep high impedance you should do it after them.

Comment: I would suggest against the proprietary parts here, because they are usually unobtainable right now. But as the OP @Maxim also considers an AD7768, unobtainable parts seem to not be an issue ;) I use fully differential instrumentation amps a lot. They have 4 opamps, so can be easily constructed using two duals, each one selected according to its purpose. The main difficulty for discrete FDINAs are not the opamps, but the resistor matching. The best matched resistors LT5400 are not as well specced as mediocre integrated difference amplifiers, despite being much more expensive.

Comment: Thank you all once again. Some comments:

Comment: Proprietary parts look really good & I found a couple of examples but as tobalt said, not available atm =(. Concerning AD7768, I actually bought the last 3 from Mouser 2 weeks ago :D. I will hence look into the 2 unity gain buffer solution and maybe use MAX7744 or OP356. As also indicated in the comments to my question, I may not need the FDA afterwards, as my voltage can be symmetrical around 0 in my application (for my ADC input). @Rokta: what you said with "...2 input opamp arent exactly only buffers..." probably refers to: limited bandwith etc.?

Comment: One more question: If I employ an RC filter also before the unity gain buffer stage (to limit the energy input from higher frequencies and hence prevent op amp saturation), from my understanding I would not decrease the input impedance as I would only have a small resistor (a couple of ohms) in series with the input and a capacitor (of a couple of nano or micro Farad) to GND (and not over the amplifier inputs / input impedance of the op amp). I read this may be good practice. I will properly filter once again after the op amp.

Comment: @Maxim I was reffering to loss of CMRR if you will connect 2 input opamps as buffers and not according to schematic in the answer.

Comment: @Maxim You need to be careful about leakage current (or insulation resistance) of capacitors. No point of having >1GOhm opamp input if capacitor in front have 10MOhm to ground.

Comment: @Rokta good point about the leakage current, thanks. Just for clarification: concerning CMRR, you mean if I just connect the 2 input opamps without the appropriate RC networks, or you mean I should in any case use a third FDA?

Comment: @maxim I suggest that you look more at theory of ina if you will use them. I cant explain everything about them in comments.